# Convert strings in list to floats and remove None?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, integer, nonetype

```
#search for option given symbol and expiration date 
list_of_dicts = 
r.options.find_options_for_stock_by_expiration(symbol,expirationDate,optionType='put')
print(list_of_dicts)



#convert list of dictionaries into single list by parameter given
parameter_a = 'bid_price'
new_list = [f[parameter_a] for f in list_of_dicts]
print(new_list)
```

After converting the list of dictionaries (`list_of_dicts`) into a single list, I get a list of strings of bid prices:

```
['7.800000', '6.300000', '6.800000', '7.300000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000']
```

My question is, how can I convert this list of strings into a list of floats? 
Basically what I need to see is something like this:

```
[7.800000, 6.300000, 6.800000, 7.300000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000]
```

And also, what should I do if the list also contains 'None'?

Comment: Aren't those `float`s, not `int`s?

Comment: My apologies, they are floats, yes

Comment: would you like to keep the `None`s, or eliminate them?

Comment: Eliminate them actually

Comment: Oh wow, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehension is the easiest way:

```
new_list = ['7.800000', '6.300000', '6.800000', '7.300000', '0.000000', '0.000000', None, '0.000000']
float_list = [float(item) if item is not None else None for item in new_list ]
>>> print(new_list)
>>> print(float_list)
['7.800000', '6.300000', '6.800000', '7.300000', '0.000000', '0.000000', None, '0.000000']
[7.8, 6.3, 6.8, 7.3, 0.0, 0.0, None, 0.0]
```

Comment: I didn't necessarily need the trailing 0s haha, thank you so much Sam!

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to round those off to the nearest dollar, so you would want them to be floats or decimals rather than integers (unless you maybe want them converted to number of pennies rather than number of dollars).

To do floats:

```
new_list = [float(f[parameter_a]) for f in list_of_dicts]
```

To do decimals:

```
from decimal import Decimal
penny = Decimal(".01")
...
new_list = [Decimal(f[parameter_a]).quantize(penny) for f in list_of_dicts]
```

Comment: Floats are numbers and can be presented different ways as strings. But still I think it sounds like you would be happier with decimals, so I will add that to answer.

Comment: Much apprish, Andrew! Thankfully the bids for my option contracts are calculated to the second decimal place haha!

Comment: No worries, I am also into trading, but I do forex, where we have prices that go to the thousandth of a penny. Still I ended up writing a Price class for forex based on Decimals rather than floats. But there is a learning curve with decimal pacakage. https://github.com/aallaire/python_forex_types/blob/master/forex_types/price.py

Comment: Will definitely check it out!

Comment: Its only good for forex trading. Won't help with stocks. And its not actually that good yet.. EDIT: but it might serve as an example of how to use decimals and such.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
new_list = ['7.800000', '6.300000', '6.800000', '7.300000', '0.000000', '0.000000', None, '0.000000']
float_list = [float(item) for item in new_list if item]

print(new_list)
print(float_list)
```

Output:

```
['7.800000', '6.300000', '6.800000', '7.300000', '0.000000', '0.000000', None, '0.000000']
[7.8, 6.3, 6.8, 7.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```